# Force type and content type

Tags: php, apache, content-type

I have a folder with some sql files that I would like to be processed as PHP and I would like the output to be text/plain. I can force sql files to be processed by PHP like this:

```
<FilesMatch "\.sql$">
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Is there a way I can set the default content-type when these files are served to be text/plain? Or will I have to use the `header` thing in the files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^(.+\.sql)$ $1 [T=text/plain]
```